# Regexp notepad++

Tags: java, regex, string, notepad++

I have a big file with links:

```
http://livetv.ru/en/livescore/
http://www.premiocentre.ru/
http://cs.rin.ru/forum/
http://www.girlsgames123.ru/zomer.html
http://wikitourist.ru/Prescott,_ARIZONA_Virginia_homes_tutorial_Made_for_All_Purchaser9851840
http://spanishrestaurant.ru/tags/%F0%FB%E1%E0/
```

How to write a regexp for notepad++ to delete all after third / ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have misunderstood since none of your examples are longer than three slashes. But here goes:

Search for:

```
(http://[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/).*
```

Replace with:

```
\1
```

If you are counting the http:// as the first two slashes, then you want to use this regex instead:

```
(http://[^/]+/).*
```

Answer (score 3):

Search for

```
^((?:[^\/]*\/){3}).*$
```

and replace it with

```
$1
```

Comment: I tried this at first too. But the {3} does not seem to work in Notepad++. Neither does the $1 in the replace expression.

Comment: @FrancisGagnon - Oh boy! I have tested it before I posted it, so **it works!** Did you turn on "Regular expression" mode in your search/replace dialog? Or what version do you use? I am using v6.2.2. (the most recent one)

Comment: Regex mode was indeed on. But I am using an older version than you are, so that may explain why it didn't work for me.